# Please check whether the proof is correct or not.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Please check my solving. I want to know where to be wrong or illogical, or where logical jumps are.

### Problem

Let $y=Tx$ be a nonsingular linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $\displaystyle\int_E f(y) dy$ exists, then $\displaystyle\int_E f(y) dy = |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E}f(Tx)dx$.

(Since $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I have to write $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ instead of $x$ and $y$, respectively. However, I will use just $x$ and $y$ since it is hard to type \mathbf for every $x$ and $y$.)

---

### Solve

1. $f=f^+ - f^-$
2. Since $f^+ \ge 0$, There exists $\{f_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ such that $f_k$ are nonnegative simple functions and $f_k\nearrow f^+$. That is $$f_k=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^{(k)}\chi_{E_i^{(k)}}\quad\text{and}\quad f_k\le f_{k+1}\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k=f^+$$
3. $\displaystyle\int_E f^+(y)dy = \int_E \lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(y)dy$
4. Since $f_k\nearrow f^+$ and $f_k\ge 0$, by M.C.T.,
   \begin{align}
   \int_E f^+(y)dy=\int_E \lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(y)dy
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E f_k(y)dy \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E \sum_{i=1}^{N} a^{(k)}_i\chi_{E^{(k)}_i}(y)dy \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_E a^{(k)}_i\chi_{E^{(k)}_i}(y)dy \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a^{(k)}_i|E^{(k)}_i| \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a^{(k)}_i\frac{|T^{-1}E^{(k)}_i|}{|\det T^{-1}|} \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a^{(k)}_i |\det T| |T^{-1}E^{(k)}_i| \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{T^{-1}E} a^{(k)}_i|\det T|\chi_{T^{-1}E^{(k)}_i}(x)dx \\
   &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{T^{-1}E} a^{(k)}_i|\det T|\chi_{E^{(k)}_i}(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T|\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{T^{-1}E} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a^{(k)}_i\chi_{E^{(k)}_i}(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T|\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{T^{-1}E} f_k(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} \lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} f^+(Tx)dx \\
   \end{align}
5. For the same way for $f^-$,
   $$\int_E f^-(y)dy = |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} f^-(Tx)dx$$
6. From the process 1,
   \begin{align}
   \int_E f(y)dy &= \int_E \left(f^+-f^-\right)(y)dy \\
   &= \int_E f^+(y)dy - \int_E f^-(y)dy \\
   &= |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} f^+(Tx)dx - |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} f^-(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} \left(f^+ - f^-\right)(Tx)dx \\
   &= |\det T| \int_{T^{-1}E} f(Tx)dx
   \end{align}

Comment: Question: when you write $f_k$ as a combination of $N$ terms $a_i^{(k)}1_{E_i^{(k)}}$, how do you know that the same $N$ works for all $f_k$?

Comment: @D_S Yes, you are right. So I have to change $N$ into $N^{(k)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok to me, if you justify that 
$$
|TE|=|\det T|\,|E|.
$$

The result you are trying to prove is the change of variable formula. Just assuming that $f$ is measurable you get directly from the [substitution formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) that
$$
\int_Ef(y)\,dy=\int_{T^{-1}E} f(Tx)\,|\det T|\,dx,
$$
where the only verification to be made is that the Jacobian of $T$ is $T$ itself.

Comment: $|TE|=|\det T||E|$ is referred in the textbook as a theorem, so I brought it. Can you say what the second sentence means? I do not understand.

Comment: I meant [the substitution formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

Comment: Can you give more detail? How can I shorten the proof?? Actually, reasons why I posted this is to know other proofs as well as to fix my wrong.

Comment: What's the hypothesis on $f $?

Comment: ??? I copied the problem exactly same as the book. What hypothesis?

Comment: The only hypothesis you mention is that $\int_Ef(y)dy$ exists. How do you know that such $f$ can be approximated by simple functions?

Comment: I used two theorems, 1. every function can be written as a limit of simple functions 2. For a nonnegative function  f, there exists $f_k\ge0$ such that $f_k\nearrow f$. They're not true???

Comment: For "any function"? No. For a measurable $f$, yes.

Comment: However, my textbook has the theorem (4.13)
(i) Every function $f$ can be written as the limit of a swequence $\{f_k\}$ of simple functions.
(ii) If $f\ge0$, the sequence can be chosen to increase to $f$, that is, chosen such that $f_k \le f_{k+1}$ for every $k$
(iii) If the function $f$ in either (i) or (ii) is measurable, then the $f_k$ can be chosen to be measurable.

Comment: You are right. The $f $ in your question is measurable, though.

Comment: I know that, for nonnegative $f$, $\int_E f$ exists if and only if $f$ is measurable. Is if fine if I consider, for $f\in(-\infty, +\infty)$ $f$ is measurable if and only if $\int f$ exists?

Comment: That is, I want to know that (1) if $\int f$ exists, then $f$ is measurable or not and (2) if $\int f$ exists and be finite (i.e. integrable), then $f$ is measurable or not. (I know that two are true for nonnegative $f$, but I do not know they are true or not for $f$, which can be negative.)

Comment: That's the thing that depends a little on context: usually, I would say that "$\int f $ exists" means "$f $ is measurable and $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are finite". But I don't know if that's how your book does it. The notation $\int f (y)dy $ doesn't help, as it is unusual for a Lebesgue integral.